# Ubuntu start docker service fail

Tags: docker, ubuntu

My docker service in my ubuntu machine doesn't work, docker rm no response.
So I restart it, but it also no response, then I interrupt
I found the docker service stop but not start, but when I try to start, it fails

```
(base) zkw@shark:~/data-auto-analysis-toolkit-backend$ sudo systemctl start docker
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xeu docker.service" for details.
```

the docker status shown below

```
(base) zkw@shark:~/data-auto-analysis-toolkit-backend$ sudo systemctl status docker
× docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2023-09-20 13:15:40 PDT; 8min ago
TriggeredBy: × docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 741951 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 741951 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      Tasks: 21
     Memory: 3.3G
        CPU: 83ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
             ├─  1215 "[dockerd]"
             ├─727983 /usr/sbin/iptables --wait -t filter -D DOCKER "" "" -i br-3eefac86b1fd -o br-3eefac86b1fd -p tcp -d 172.18.0.2 --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
             └─728747 /usr/sbin/iptables --wait -t nat -C DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 32786 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.5:8080 "!" -i docker0

Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.
Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit process 727983 (iptables) remains running after unit stopped.
Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit process 728747 (iptables) remains running after unit stopped.
Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: docker.service: Unit process 1215 (dockerd) remains running after unit stopped.
Sep 20 13:15:40 shark systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
```

docker version

```
(base) zkw@shark:~/data-auto-analysis-toolkit-backend$ docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           24.0.5
 API version:       1.43
 Go version:        go1.20.6
 Git commit:        ced0996
 Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:35:18 2023
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Context:           default
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

It should work after stoping it and restart it

Comment: Even though manually restart the machine solved this issue.
I still wonder what is the reason that made this issue occur.